# How to use the current visitor's account in SSAS query? [MOSS + PPS + SSAS]

Tags: moss, ssas, performancepoint

I'm using MOSS2010 + Performance Point + Analysis services. Here's the questions:

1. How to get the current visitor's account in PPS report?
2. How to use the current visitor's account in SSAS query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post may help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/performancepoint/archive/2010/03/25/passing-filter-values-on-the-url-to-performancepoint-services-web-parts.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to configure your PerformanePoint 2010 data source to use `Per-User Identity`.

Then access the UserName MDX function:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.x AS UserName
SELECT Measures.x ON COLUMNS
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

References:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/performancepoint/archive/2010/01/05/new-authentication-options-for-data-sources.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can only customize scorecards with the custom scorecards transformations. The reports cannot be customized.

You can perform 4 types of scorecards transformation : PerUser, PreQuery, PostQuery and PreRender. From there, it's C#, so do whatever you like.

To create a Scorecard transformation, you will need to inherit from IGridViewTransform. You will need to include references to Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.Client and Microsoft.SharePoint.

See the following link for a tutorial on how to achieve this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff606776.aspx

For your information, since there's not much documentation on the subject, I found that it is a good idea to XML Serialize your "viewData" object to take a closer look at what's inside and understand the general feel of it. The "Cells" objects are pretty strange, starting from the end of the scorecard and getting backward.

Good luck!